# IIS 7 site redirecting to default IIS Welcome Page

Tags: iis-7

I have set up a site in IIS 7. However, it redirects to the default page.

I have set the physical path the the folder location.

What trivial step am i missing?

Comment: Please, verify your bindings

Comment: Type: http, IP Address: All unassigned, Port: 82

Comment: Anything wrong in this?

Comment: What is it you wish to have happen?  It is difficult for us to help you if we don't know what the end goal is.

Comment: And are you talking default IIS site or default page for your site?

Comment: It goes to the IIS welcome screen and not to the index.html in my site directory

Comment: Is your url goes to port 82? Do you have your index.html in the default pages?

Comment: It goes to localhost:82 when i hit on browse. My home page is located at localhost:82/index.html. Why doesn't it display the index.html by default instead of showing the IIS welcome screen. strange. I even updated the default page setting to have index.html at the top. I am definitely missing a very trivial step.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the default pages fixes it.